# python df: convert date index from milliseconds to days

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime, indexing

I'm absolutely struggling with converting my date index from milliseconds to normal formal like 2020-04-21. I'm able to convert a single value to a datetime using `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(1586563200000)/1000)`which gives me `datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 11, 0, 0)`

Then i use `tsp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` to remove the hours/seconds but in vain as my output is `2020-04-11 23:59:59.999`

My issue is that i have a pandas dataframe and most operations I'm trying on it for my date index don't work. So I have tried looping across the date and re-indexing the result but this seems incredibly inefficient.

```
no = float(data.close_time.count())
time = []
x= 0
while x != no:
    a = data.close_time[x]
    tsp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(a)/1000)
    time.append(tsp)
    x += 1
data.index = time
```

Would really appreciate any help, light on the issue! Thank You

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `pandas.to_datetime`

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(1490195805, unit='s')
Timestamp('2017-03-22 15:16:45')
>>> pd.to_datetime(1490195805433502912, unit='ns')
Timestamp('2017-03-22 15:16:45.433502912')
```

If you want round by hour

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(1490195805//3600*3600, unit='s')
Timestamp('2017-03-22 15:00:00')
```

If you want round by day

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(1490195805//(3600*24)*3600*24, unit='s')
Timestamp('2017-03-22 00:00:00')
```

similar to milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks appreciated
'    time = pd.to_datetime(data.close_time//(3600*24)*3600*24, unit='s')
    data.index = time'
This gives me an error. however looping through worked so thanks for that. 
Would it be possible without looping?